# ajax call always going to the same method in my web api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

EDIT:  PER Felipe's answer, I changed the code in the webapiconfig to the following, and it works great-

```
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        name:="DefaultApi", _
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
    )
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="API Default", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults:=New With { _
.id = RouteParameter.[Optional] _
```

})

I have a web api controller with 4 functions-

```
     <HttpGet> _
<ActionName("AllCerts")> _
Public Function GetCerts() As Object
    Dim LWCERTS As Array = objCert.GetCertificates
    Return LWCERTS
End Function


<HttpGet> _
<ActionName("MyCerts")> _
Public Function GetMyCert() As Object

    Dim lwMyCerts As Array = objCert.GetCertificates(Utilities.GetLogin())

    Return lwMyCerts

End Function

<HttpGet> _
<ActionName("GetValueDDA")> _
Public Function GetDDABanks()
    Dim objDDABankNum As New LucasEntities.Business.EF_DDA
    Dim lwDDABankNum As Array = objDDABankNum.GetDDABankJSON()

    Return lwDDABankNum

End Function
'' POST api/caapproval
<HttpPost> _
<ActionName("CertDtlsByID")> _
Public Function Post(value As CertDetailModel) As Object
    Dim objCertPosting As New LucasEntities.Business.EF_CertificatePosting
    Dim lwMyCertDetails As String = objCertPosting.GetBorrowingBaseAdvanceRequestJSON()

    Return lwMyCertDetails

End Function
```

In my data service, I have the following ajax call-

```
         var getallCertificates = function (CertificatesObservable) {
        var dataObservableArray = ko.observableArray([]);
        var newJ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/caapproval/AllCerts/",
            async: false,
            success: function (dataIn) {
                newJ = $.parseJSON(dataIn);

                CertificatesObservable([]);

                     dataIn.forEach(function (p) {
                        var certificate = new certificateModel(p.clientID, p.lwCertID, p.requestDate, p.userName, p.statusDescription, p.statusCode, p.statusDesc, p.ceoUserName, p.clientName, p.clientNumber, p.borrowBaseCount, p.advRequestCount, p.certType);
                        CertificatesObservable.push(certificate);
                    });
                    return CertificatesObservable(data);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
            }

        });
        return CertificatesObservable(newJ);
    }
```

Here is my RouteConfig class-

```
 Public Class RouteConfig
Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")


    routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Default", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
End Sub
```

End Class

When I put breakpoints in my controller, I see that the Post function under the CertDtlsByID actionName is always run, NOT GetCerts under the AllCerts ActionName.  Being new to web api and routing, what am i doing wrong that causes the "Post" method to always be called?

When I run the web api directly in the browser, Chrome shows the following error-

```
 Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Object GetCerts() on type LucasNetApp.CAApprovalController System.Object GetMyCert() on type LucasNetApp.CAApprovalController System.Object GetDDABanks() on type LucasNetApp.CAApprovalController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net web api the routing is controlled by the `WebApiConfig.cs` file on the `App_Start` folder.
The `ActionName` attribute does not work because it is a behavouir of the asp.net mvc.

Open the `WebApiConfig.cs` file and try to add theses routes configurations:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApiGet",
                           url:="api/{controller}",
                           defaults:=New With {.action = "Get"},
                           constraints:=new With {.httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)})

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApiWithAction",
                           url:="api/{controller}/{action}")
```

I am not sure about the `Vb.Net` sintaxe, looks the same code in `C#`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet",
                           "api/{controller}",
                           new {action = "Get"},
                           new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)});

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction",
                           "api/{controller}/{action}");
```